# How to make PayPal recurring donation button for OTHER nonprofits

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I would like to include [PayPal recurring donation buttons](http://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/get-started/create-recurring-donation-button) on my website so that users can donate to other nonprofits/charities of my choosing. My website would include many of these buttons, and all money would be sent directly to these charities. How would I go about this? As far as I know, one can only create donate/subscription buttons where the money goes to the creator of the button. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you create the button make sure to uncheck the option to save the button at PayPal, which would bind it to that account.

When you do that the HTML code provided will include a "business" parameter that would be the email address of the account the profile should be created with and the money should drop in to.

Another option would be using the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/), with which you can specify the account the money should go to with the SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID parameter.

Comment: Is there a way for me to do this with [PayPal Giving Fund](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/search-cause)? I'd be limited to the nonprofits on that site, but I want to create a subscription service so that people can donate a few cents daily to their favorite charities. Since all proceeds would go directly to the charities (no extra fees), PayPal Giving Fund seems like the best option. Do you know how to get code for each "Donate Now" box like the one included [here](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/search-cause?charityId=25936&s=1), except set to daily instead of monthly?